# Get C#-Object-Array out of a JSON-String

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object

So, this is my class:

```
public class User
{
    public User() { }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

And this is how my JSON-String looks like:

```
{"results":[{"FirstName":"firstname1","LastName":"lastname1","Password":"TestPassword","Username":"TestUser","createdAt":"2015-03-02T17:36:25.232Z","objectId":"a8bKXDg2Y2","updatedAt":"2015-03-02T20:35:48.755Z"},{"FirstName":"firstname2","LastName":"lastname2","Password":"TestPw","Username":"TestUser2","createdAt":"2015-03-02T20:35:26.604Z","objectId":"2XPIklE3uW","updatedAt":"2015-03-02T20:35:53.712Z"}]}
```

I would like to get a User[] users out of it.
My Problem is the {"results:":[....]}-Part.

I've tried it this way:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
User[] user = js.Deserialize<User[]>(jsonString);
```

but I think the results-Part is messing everything up somehow.
What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Whenever you have the JSON I always recommend going to http://json2csharp.com. It will generate the classes you need to deserialize into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try defining a wrapping model that will reflect your JSON structure:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public User[] Results { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can go ahead and deserialize your JSON string back to this wrapping model:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
MyModel model = js.Deserialize<MyModel>(jsonString);
```

and now there's nothing preventing you from getting your users collection back:

```
User[] user = model.Results;
```

Comment: thank you, this might work - but is is a good way to create a wrapper for every class?

Comment: Of course that it is a good way. You must match exactly the JSON structure you are deserializing. Otherwise how do you expect a JSON serializer to automagically know what you are trying to achieve? It works by type introspection and properties matching. So make sure you have the proper structure when serializing/deserializing.

Comment: Thank you very much! Helped me a lot. (I need to wait about 7 minutes to accept this answer, I'll do it later)

Answer (score 1):

You need another layer on your model

```
public class Data
{
   public User[] results { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize the `Data` class